# How do I put multiple integers into int* tab; in two different loops separated by 0 eg. [1,1,1,0,1,1] in VS 2019 in C

Tags: c

I am writing a emulator for Turing machine subtraction and, to start, I need to have the `m` and `n` converted into 1s and one 0s. For example, if `m = 3`, `n = 2`, the output would be `[1,1,1,0,1,1]` in the `int` array.

I tried using `malloc` to allocate memory for `int* tab` and, after that, I simply put the first ones in the first loop, then append a 0, then, in another loop, I'm adding the `n` 1s.

The problem is with Visual Studio, I think, because I tried the same code in vim and the output was correct. In VS, the output of 1s is correct but, instead of 0, I get some random negative number.

Here's the code:

```
    scanf_s("%d", &m);
    printf("n = ");
    scanf_s("%d", &n);
    int* tab = malloc(sizeof(int) * (n + m + 1));
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        tab[i] = 1;
    }
    tab[i + 1] = 0;
    int j = 0;
    for (j = i + 1; j < n + i + 1; j++)
    {
        tab[j] = 1;
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < n + m + 1; k++)
    {
        printf("%d", tab[k]);
    }
```

[The bad output from VS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtBrd.png)

Answer (score 0):

I believe

```
 tab[i + 1] = 0;
```

is the problem. From previous loop execution the control will only come out when `i<m` is false, i.e., for the case when `i == m`, as per the increment statement.

Now, you want to put the `0` at this index, not at `index + 1`.

Change to `tab[i] = 0;`.

Now, the *probable* reason for the negative number: The content of the memory location returned by `malloc()` is indeterminate, so if you miss to write the index when `i == m` (you were writing from `0` to `m-1`, then from `m+1` to `m+n-1`), while reading it'll return that indeterminate value.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `tab[i + 1] = 0;` line. When the preceding loop has finished, then `i` will be *equal to* `m` — that is to say, the `i` value will *already* be "one beyond the end".

So, just change that to: `tab[i] = 0;` and you should be fine.

Comment: Yeah it helped, but i am wondering why the output in any other ide is good.. anyway thanks for the answer!

Comment: @Majki All I can suggest is that the vim 'compiler' (whatever that is) initializes the array to all zeros (which it is *allowed* to do but not *required*). In that case, even though you skip over the actual place where you intend to put the `0`, it is there by default.